# Change the filter widget type in a views

Tags: 7, views

When adding a reference field as a filter in a views the default widget of the filter is drop down.
Is there a way to change it to a auto complete widget?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like [Views Autocomplete Filters](http://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters).  The D7 version is in development but it sounds like it might be worth a try.